# SWI Prolog PIO DCGs can't deal with null bytes

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a file that is just the letter `a`. I can "parse" it with this DCG:

```
identity([]) --> [].
identity([H|T]) --> [H], identity(T).
```

```
?- phrase_from_file(identity(X), "jah.txt").
X = [97] ;
false.
```

This is correct-- but when I add a `NUL` byte to my file:

[image]

When I attempt to post the above query, Prolog locks up forever. I guess it has to do something with null-terminated strings somewhere, but I'm not sure what to do here-- I'm using DCGs to parse binary files, so I need to be able to deal with null bytes.

Comment: Did you check what's happening using e.g. trace/0? https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Looks like a bug - swipl shouldn't just segfault - please raise at https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/issues/issues

Comment: @brebs It doesn't segfault, it just computes infinitely, as if it were in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to pass `type(binary)` as an option to `phrase_from_file/3`.

```
phrase_from_file(identity(X), "jah.txt", [type(binary)]).
```