# Seek to position in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Given this marker, what's the most efficient way of finding its position in a large binary file (~80Mb)

```
metadata_marker("\xAB\xCD\xEFMaxMind.com").
```

Comment: Probably as a DCG, using `phrase_from_file(..., [type(binary)])` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166373/swi-prolog-pio-dcgs-cant-deal-with-null-bytes

Comment: For such things depending upon how efficiency is defined, the answer might be to use a fast C library and use [Foreign Language Interface](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreign) to call the C functions. The other day I had a similar need and just used grep because the file was a few GBs in size.

Comment: Why is this a binary file? Looks like a text file to me. Or do you just mean the string without the name?

Comment: The file is binary, but there are encoded markers inside that are used to delimit sections within. `metadata_marker/1` just returns one of such markers.